# What are the synonyms for 'face-to-face'?

Tags: synonyms

I found in dictionary - opposite, but that is not the synonym that I am looking for.

I am interested for something like 'local'. For example, "We work with customers face-to-face as well as remotely". With what can I replace "face-to-face" in this sentense?

Comment: Why is "locally" not an option, especially when the opposite is "remotely"?

Comment: I think it is an option, but maybe there are other synonyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're probably looking for something like ***on-site***. You're actually looking for an antonym to *remote* rather than a synonym of *face-to-face*.

Related: [How do I phrase "remote work" better?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72328/how-do-i-phrase-remote-work-better)

Answer (score 1):

There are special usages of **personally** and **actual**:

**personally 1.** Without the intervention of another; in person: I thanked them personally. AHDEL

**in person** - in the flesh (WordNet)

x x x x x

We work with **actual** people.

However, register is important - I would rarely use 'in the flesh' or 'actual people' in advertising literature, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

How about *directly*?
e.g. You have to love our customers - we build products for them, and the best way to improve our products is to work with them directly.

Answer (score -2):

"**Presential**" if it means that happen in the presence of or it is an actual presence. You can have a *face-to-face interview* on video, or a *presential interview*.
We work with presential or remote clients.

Comment: Posts without adequate reference(s), such as linking to a cited definition, are generally looked down on here: we're after authoritative answers rather than unsupported personal opinion (see [answer]). You can [edit] your post to add a dictionary definition of "presential", but I think you'll find that it derives from "present" [time] rather than "presence" [place], which makes this answer incorrect...